# How to print request , response, url with date & time stamp in flutter as we do in android

Tags: flutter

My requirement is i got one flutter task to complete, now i m in  almost completion stage, but client requested for having  url,request,response,date & time stamp data to be printed in flutter logs as we do in android studio logs this they are requesting for checking the api & ui navigation fastness in flutter comparing time tajken in flutter to android with same backend server.

so i m stuck in knowing how to print  url,request,response,date & time stamp in flutter.Any flutter developers who seeing this please help if this is completed i can submit my flutter task to client.
Exception below kind of logs in flutter as we do in android in

Request with url:

--> POST https://app-test-sas.com/uh/user/auth/1892/Usrname
2022-01-25 18:10:35.654 12350-13030/com.example.test D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2022-01-25 18:10:35.654 12350-13030/com.example.test D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 112
2022-01-25 18:10:35.654 12350-13030/com.example.test D/OkHttp: X-Auth-Token: 3737474884848487474747747448488
2022-01-25 18:10:35.656 12350-13030/com.example.test D/OkHttp: {"appVersion":0140001,"authType":0,"usedId:"test"}
2022-01-25 18:10:35.656 12350-13030/com.example.test D/OkHttp: --> END POST (112-byte body)

Response with url:
-- 200 https://app-test-sas.com/uh/user/auth/1892/Usrname (362ms)
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 13:26:15 GMT
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: content-length: 1194
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: access-control-allow-headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization,X-API-KEY,
2022-01-25 18:56:14.381 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: access-control-allow-credentials: true
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: x-frame-options: DENY
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: x-content-type-options: nosniff
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: cache-control: no-cache
2022-01-25 18:56:14.382 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: alternate-protocol: 443:npn-spdy/3
2022-01-25 18:56:14.384 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: {"resCode":"000","resDesc":"SUCCESS","userId":"test","userName":"neeraj"}
2022-01-25 18:56:14.384 12350-14102/com.example.test D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (1194-byte body)

how to print  url,request,response,date & time stamp in flutter as above.
Please help i m stuck with this.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Like httpIntercepter in retrofit okhttp like in android suggest any thing in flutter?

Comment: @Richard Heap Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ask your client to use this tool: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/network

Comment: Like httpIntercepter in retrofit okhttp like in android suggest any thing in flutter?

Comment: Its not only about client as a developer we also have same expectations

Comment: @Hemavathi read the blog and select your own: https://medium.com/flutter-community/three-easy-ways-to-debug-network-requests-in-flutter-53043e898929

Comment: @Hemavathi or checkout this package network_logger: ^1.0.0

Comment: network_logger: ^1.0.0 can u give some example

Comment: using network_logger: ^1.0.0 we can print request,resposne,url in flutter logs?

Comment: @Hemavathi if you visit this ppackage it is clearly written ther that Network logger with well designed user interface to inspect network traffic logs. Included with Dio interceptor. You can start and inspect traffic just by writing 2 lines of code.You are 3 steps ahead from viewing http traffic logs on well designed GUI. from GUI you can also print anything in your log